# Can I evaluate the following limit?

Tags: limits

I need to evaluate $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log(\cos (x))}{x-\sin( x)}$. I apply L'Hospital and I get that it is $\frac{1}{0}$. Am I wrong?

Comment: i got that with l'hopital  -tan/(1-cos) then -sec^2 / - sin = 1 / 0

Answer (score 3):

You're not wrong.  Note that we have

$$\frac{\log(\cos(x))}{x-\sin(x)}\sim \frac{-\frac12 x^2}{\frac16 x^3}=-\frac 3x=O\left(\frac1x\right)$$

But the limit fails to exist since the limit from the left-hand side is $+\infty$ while the limit from the right-hand side is $-\infty$.